# Determining SSL/TLS encryption?

Tags: c#, ssl

I am trying to check some code to see how secure a SSL/TLS connection is but I am not sure how to determine this.

The code uses a certificate created with these arguments:

```
makecert
"-pe -n ""CN=certificatename"" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -in ""certname"" -is my -ir LocalMachine -sp ""Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"" -sy 12 ""certificatefilename.cer"""
```

When the Client is connecting it creating an sslStream like this:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(SocketServerClass.serverCertificate, False, SslProtocols.Default, False)
```

Any information would be great to determine details regarding the bit size and security method. Thank you!

UPDATE:

I looked at sslStream as you suggested when connecting and got this:

CipherAlgorithm = Aes128 {26126} 
CipherStrength = 128 
HashStrength = 160 
KeyExchangeAlgorithm = RsaKeyX {41984} 
KeyExchangeStrength = 1024 
SslProtocol = Tls {192}

*How secure is this? "Military" grade?*

Comment: Do you mean thinks like `SslStream.CipherAlgorithm` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.cipheralgorithm.aspx and `SslStream.CipherStrength` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.cipherstrength.aspx ?

Comment: How do you gauge the level of security?  What does "military" grade TLS communication mean?

Comment: Also keep in mind TLS may negotiate different cipher details on each session and probably will have differing cipher details for each server that it's connecting to.  TLS supports unencrypted connections.

Comment: I am thinking about requirements for US army usage. If they have any for communication.

Comment: If they have requirements, they can put them in the server or the client.  A TLS node can require a "minimum" cipher.  The other end, if it supports that cipher, will simply agree to use it during the negotiation.  The likelihood that what you see now will be the same in a "US Army" scenario is slim.  Even it was the same, that's what they've configured their nodes to accept for a cipher and thus clearly "military grade".  But, that's independent of a cert.

Comment: i.e. each connect can have different cryptographic configuration; what you see now is irrelevant to what you'd see in another connection like in a US Army connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot determine security of SSL/TLS connection until it is established, because ciphersuite will be negotiated only after connection is made.
Use Wireshark to check the first packets of SSL/TLS connection and see which ciphersuite was chosen.

Answer (score 2):

The [SslStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) exposes several properties that provide information about the connection:

- [SslStream.CipherAlgorithm Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.cipheralgorithm.aspx)
- [SslStream.CipherStrength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.cipherstrength.aspx)
- [SslStream.HashAlgorithm Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.hashalgorithm.aspx)
- [SslStream.HashStrength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.hashstrength.aspx)
- [SslStream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.keyexchangealgorithm.aspx)
- [SslStream.KeyExchangeStrength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.keyexchangestrength.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I tested this and got this:

CipherAlgorithm = Aes128 {26126}
CipherStrength = 128
HashStrength = 160
KeyExchangeAlgorithm = RsaKeyX {41984}
KeyExchangeStrength = 1024
SslProtocol = Tls {192}

How secure is this? "Military" grade?